# HTML Special Characters in URL string

Tags: php, functions, advanced-custom-fields

I am using this code to convert the `&` to its html entity but it doesn't work. The output is passed to a field in gravity forms.

```
<a href="/enquiry/?event=<?php $urlst=get_field('fl_name');htmlspecialchars($urlst, ENT_QUOTES);echo $urlst; ?>">Make a request</a>
```

If I have `fl_name= Music & TV Shows` then in my gravity forms output i only see `Music`

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is use the tools that WordPress has provided for you to construct your URLs.

In this solution you're building an array of URL parameters with keys and values, then you're "attaching" these parameters to the array using `add_query_arg`.

You can reuse this approach for all your URLs, and simply add/adjust your `$parameters` array as you need it, and the URL.

```php
$parameters = [
    'event' => get_field( 'fl_name' ),
];

$final_url = add_query_arg( $parameters, site_url( '/enquiry/' ) );
```

then simply echo out your `$final_url` wherever you need it:

```html
<a href="<?php echo $final_url; ?>">Make a request</a>
```

A one-liner version of all of this is:

```html
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( [ 'event' => get_field( 'fl_name' ) ], site_url( '/enquiry/' ) ) ;?>">Make a request</a>
```